# How to custom handle iteration in python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Supposing that we have a dictinary:

```
links={"foo":"url1","bar":"url2","baz":"url3",}
```

I would like by running one for loop if it is possible like:

```
for link in links:
    ...
    print(next_dictinary_value)
```

to print the next value of dictionaly, for the last one I want to print the first.
The purpose is every dictinary pair to print (connect) to another pair with out any pair conection creating a cycle(linking to each other).

Comment: I do not understand your last sentence. Can you provide an example of the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're asking for something like the following:

```
keys = links.keys()
n = len(keys)
for i in range(n):
    thisKey = keys[i]
    nextKey = keys[(i + 1) % n]
    nextValue = links[nextKey]
    print thisKey, nextValue
```

But be aware that a dictionary is not sorted, so you could get back the keys in any order.

Answer (score 2):

```
links={"foo":"url1","bar":"url2","baz":"url3",}
it = iter(links)
for link in links:
    print it.next()

... baz
... foo
... bar
```

but try this:

```
it = iter(links)
it.next()
for link in links:
    try:
        print it.next()
    except StopIteration:
        it = iter(links)
        print it.next()


... foo
... bar
... baz
```

".... It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key:..."

Answer (score -1):

You could get all the keys with keys = links.keys(). Then use them to iterate over the dictionary using the keys. Example:

```
>>> links={"foo":"url1","bar":"url2","baz":"url3",}
>>> k = links.keys()
>>> for i in range(0, len(k)):
...     print(links[ k[i] ])
... 
url3
url1
url2
```

Variable i contains the current position.